# login com php e angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Criei um formulário de login.
Estou quase finalizando a autenticação e só o que falta é conseguir redirecionar o usuário para a página certa.

AngularJS:

```
app.controller("LoginController", function ($scope, $http, $state) {

$scope.loginInfo = {
    nome: undefined,
    senha: undefined
}

$scope.loginUser = function () {
    var data = {
        nome: $scope.loginInfo.nome,
        senha: $scope.loginInfo.senha
    }

    $http.post("admin/php/login.php", data).then(function(response){
        //console.log(response);
        $state.go("admin/views/painel", response);
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.error(error);
    });
    //})
}

});
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Use $location.path('admin/views/painel')

Comment: Apareceu isso no console:
"$location is not defined(…)"

Comment: Adicione em seu controller ficando assim: app.controller("LoginController", function ($scope,$http,$state,$location)

Comment: Deu certo.
Valeu.